# NGXS: loading and error messages in state

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I'm new to NGXS and right now i'm trying to add on each of my state a loading and an error object. The easiest way would be to add a `loading: boolean` and an `errors: {}` on my state model.

But I decided to create another state named `ApiRequestState` which basically just contains the error and loading fields, for example:

```
export class ApiRequestStateModel {
   loading: boolean;
   errors: {}
}
```

Then have an action and state class to manage the values in it. This works for the most part, except that right now I have a page where I have to load several components and each component connects to the API all at once. The problem is I only have one loading and error state so I don't know how to track all of them at once.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can also track the number of requests and set the loader when they are all settled

Answer (score 2):

without really knowing what your rootstate looks like its gonna be hard to answer.
but given that you have a `loading: boolean` state, you can definitely change it to an array of strings instead that would look like

```js
loading = ['somerequest', 'anotherrequest', 'onemorerequest'];

//and when something is done
loading = loading.filter(x => x != 'thefinishedrequest')
```

once you do that, you easily determine if it is loading by reading

```js
isLoading = loading.length > 0
```

note: you can event just use a `loadingCounter:number`, but that will really not give you any info on what is loading

Comment: This is actually a good suggestion, i'll try this and accept it as the answer once I get it working. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up not doing this, there was a lot of problems encountered with several use-cases that I was doing in my app. I just used a custom HTTP interceptor for now, then just subscribe (completed, error) to the dispatch to get the errors and set the loading flag for each component.